# Django version of a database trigger?

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models, triggers

I have two tables: Cameras & Timestamp,
Timestamp has a foreign key to cameraID.
Both camera and timestamp have a 'State' field.
Each timestamp entry has a camera and a current state.
I want to update the Camera.State value when Timestamp.State for that camera is updated. In SQL I know how to do this with a database trigger. But I am not sure how to achieve this in Django

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two options: use [Django signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/signals/) or modify the `Timestamp.save()` to implement the desired behavior.

Example:

```
class Timestamp(models.Model):
    ...
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Camera.objects.filter(pk=self.camera_id).update(state=self.state)
        super(Timestamp, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: How would I write a unitTest for this? I tried `camera1 = Camera.objects.create(name='Camera1', url='google.com', currentState=False)

        timestamp = TimeStamp.objects.create(camera=camera1, state=True)


        self.assertTrue(camera1.currentState)`

Comment: Yes, I would also do something like this. Why didn't it work?

Comment: I am not sure. The values update correctly on the site. But when running the tests, the test fails "AssertionError: False is not true"

Comment: just a safety check - did you call `timestamp.save()` after creation? Did you reload `camera1` afterwards?